# How do I enable autoresizing for a Flex UIComponent?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a class which extends UIComponent and draws directly onto a Sprite contained within. Currently I'm (probably incorrectly) listening to the Event.RESIZE event and drawing the contents when the width and height are non-zero. The problem is that even though I've passed percentage widths to the instance tag, it doesn't appear to be resized along with other Flex components on the page, certainly the resize event isn't being fired at all.

I've hacked it for the moment by binding the width and height to a container which does resize, but how should I really be handling this?

**Update** :
It turns out I was setting the width and height somewhere in the redraw method (I have no recollection of why I did this!). I shall go hang my head in shame now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to provide more information. I'm doing exactly the same, and it works smoothly for me. Perhaps the answer lies somewhere else: e.g. exactly what type of container do you use?  Isn't it possible that the space gained/lost on resizing gets allocated to some other component within the cointainer? Try substituting your own component with an mx:Box with some colored background, and see if *that* resizes with the container.

Comment: Fair enough, it's a touch more complex than I described. I'll try and figure out what I'm adding to the UIComponent that makes it break.